# Oracle SQL Cross Tab Query

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, report, crosstab

I have a table which has the following structure and sample data:

```
ITEM   LOC   STOCK
0001   KS5    10
0001   KS6    30
0002   KS5    10
0002   KS6    20
```

I need to query cross tab so that I get

```
ITEM  KS5  KS6
0001  10   30
0002  10   20
```

The LOC (KS5 and KS6) can vary and new locations can be added.

How can I get the desired result?

Comment: It's called pivoting, isn't it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For dynamically generated results you need some dynamic PLSQL solution, something like this procedure creating view `v_list_loc`:

```
create or replace procedure p_list_loc is

  v_sql varchar2(32000) := '';

begin

  for c in (select distinct loc from test order by loc) loop
    v_sql := v_sql || '''' ||c.loc|| ''' '||c.loc||',';
  end loop;

  v_sql := 'create or replace view v_list_loc as '
    ||'select * from (select item, loc, stock from test) pivot (sum(stock) '
    ||'for (loc) in ('||rtrim(v_sql, ',')||'))';

  execute immediate v_sql;

end p_list_loc;
```

In procedure code replace `test` with your table name. Compile this procedure, run and select results from generated view `v_list_loc`:

```
SQL> exec p_list_loc;

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed

SQL> select * from v_list_loc;

ITEM         KS5        KS6
----- ---------- ----------
0001          10         30
0002          10         20
```

Every time when new values in column `loc` appears you need to execute procedure before selecting from view.

Answer (score 2):

Please try this query .

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ITEM ,LOC ,STOCK
        FROM   TABLE_NAME)
PIVOT  (SUM(STOCK) FOR (LOC) IN ('KS5' , 'KS6'))
ORDER BY ITEM;
```

Regards.

Comment: Hi Florin, 
Thanks.

Is there any way that instead of specifying KS5 and KS6, I write a subquery that would pick the locations dynamically as new locations would also be added later.

Answer (score 0):

Try and modify SQL as below:

```
SELECT *
FROM   (SELECT ITEM ,LOC ,STOCK
        FROM   TABLE_NAME)
PIVOT  (SUM(quantity) AS sum_quantity FOR (ITEM) IN (SELECT DISNTINCT(LOC) FROM TABLE_NAME))
ORDER BY ITEM;
```