# Duplicate id rows with few columns to unique id row with many columns Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, database, oracle, select, pivot

I have a pole table that can have one to four streetlights on it. Each row has a pole ID and the type (a description) of streetlight. I need the ID's to be unique with a column for each of the possible streetlights. The type/description can anyone of 26 strings.

I have something like this:

```
ID   Description
----------------
1    S 400
1    M 200
1    HPS 1000
1    S 400
2    M 400
2    S 250
3    S 300
```

What I need:

```
ID   Description_1   Description_2   Description_3   Description_4
------------------------------------------------------------------
1    S 400           M 200           HPS 1000        S 400
2    M 400           S 250
3    S 300
```

The order the descriptions get populated in the description columns is not important, e.g. for ID = 1 the HPS 1000 value could be in description column 1, 2, 3, or 4. So, long as all values are present.

I tried to pivot it but I don't think that is the right tool.

```
select * from table t
pivot (
max(Description) for ID in (1, 2, 3))
```

Because there are ~3000 IDs I would end up with a table that is ~3001 rows wide...

I also looked at this [Oracle SQL Cross Tab Query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30023754/oracle-sql-cross-tab-query) But it is not quite the same situation.

What is the right way to solve this problem?

Comment: Do you know the maximum number of columns you want to generate?

Comment: Why s 400 repeated twice?. What happens if same description repeats 100 times?

Comment: @Sam you can have many streetlights of the same type on one pole. There are 26 types of streetlights. So, values will be repeated often.

Comment: @GordonLinoff It would be the ID plus the 4 possible descriptions so 5 total.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `row_number()` and conditional aggregation:

```
select 
    id,
    max(case when rn = 1 then description end) description_1,
    max(case when rn = 2 then description end) description_2,
    max(case when rn = 3 then description end) description_3,
    max(case when rn = 4 then description end) description_4
from (
    select t.*, row_number() over(partition by id order by description) rn
    from mytable t
) t
group by id
```

This handles up to 4 descriptions per `id`. To handle more, you can just expand the `select` clause with more conditional `max()`s.